# Cannot deploy to iOS in Titanium Studio

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

So, I am having difficulty deploying to my ipod touch from Titanium Studio. I get this error when trying to deploy:

```
[DEBUG] Detected module for commonjs: ti.cloud 2.2.0 @ /Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/commonjs/ti.cloud/2.2.0
[INFO] Performing clean build
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.1.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1484, in main
    execute_xcode("iphoneos%s" % iphone_version,args,False)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.1.GA/iphone/builder.py", line 1239, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
  File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.1.GA/iphone/run.py", line 41, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 1
```

I've tried deleting the iphone build folder, doesn't work. And I don't think that I should be needing to restart TS or anything. There's got to be an easier way. If this helps, I have a lot of .pngs and I've heard that replacing them fixes the problem, but I do not want to replace all of them. There are over 500 pngs in my project. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `Project > Clean...`, select your project and then recompile.

If that doesn't work, delete your project from Ti Studio (Don't actually delete the files from your HD). Create a new project and then copy over the assets from your old project. Recompile.